# Changes the open/close time for the 4H timeframe

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to build a script which changes the open/close time for the candles in a 4H timeframe. For example, my 4H candles are currently built based on the 1H candles of 8am, 9am, 10am and 11am. But, what about if I want them to be build based on the 7am, 8am, 9am, 10am candles or starting in any other hour? Is there a way to do this?

**What I tried:**

Using the 1H timeframe, I have tried to recreate the 4H candles using this logic:

```
//Get the highest/Lowest price (wick) of the last 4 hours

high_4h = ta.highest(high,4)
low_4h = ta.lowest(low,4)    

//Get the highest/Lowest price in body candle of the last 4 hours. However, I do not get a usable value for the plotcandle() function. 

candle_high = ta.highestbars(high,4)
candle_low = ta.lowestbars(low,4)

// Plot the the 4H candles

plotcandle(candle_high,high_4h,low_4h,candle_low,"Custom 4h candles")
```

This should plot the 4H candles. However, it seems to be a problem with the ta.highestbars() and ta.lowestbars() functions. I do not get the result intended.

Am I in the right direction? Or maybe there is a function that I am missing which allows me to change the server time to different UTCs, which can create the candles easier.